# Time equation of following

Tags: c++, c

What will be the time complexity of the following ?

```
int x = 0;
for (int i = n / 2; i < n; i++) {
  if (i % 5 == 0) break;
  for (int j = 1; j < n; j += 2) {
    x++;
    x *= 2;
  }
}
```

Comment: What do *you* think? Why do you think that?

Comment: seems like O(n^2) to me.

Comment: This sounds like a homework question

Comment: A good challenge on this question:  This calculation can be rewritten to be O(1) (provided your CPU has a barrel shifter).  Can you do it?

Answer (score 4):

The inner loop is O(n).  The outer loop runs not more than 5 times.  So overall, O(n).